# Matrix inequality $(A-B)^2 \leq c (A+B)^2$ ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrix-analysis, nonnegative-matrices, linear-algebra

Let A and B be positive semidefinite matrices. It is not hard to see that $(A-B)^2 \leq 2A^2 + 2B^2$. In fact, $2A^2 + 2B^2 - (A-B)^2 = (A+B)^2$ is positive semidefinite.

My question is: Is there a constant c (independent of A and B and the dimension) such that

$$(A-B)^2 \leq c (A+B)^2?$$

Thanks.

Comment: [edited only to TeXify the title]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no such $c$ even if we use only $2 \times 2$ matrices.
For any $c \geq 1$ let $A,B$ be the positive-semidefinite matrices
$$
A = \left( \begin{array}{lc} c^2 & c \cr c & 1 \end{array} \right),
\phantom\infty
B = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{array} \right).
$$
of rank $1$.  Then we calculate that the difference
$$
D := c(A+B)^2 - (A-B)^2
$$
has determinant $(c-1)^2 - 4c^3 < 0$, and is thus not positive semidefinite.

In fact this counterexample works for all $c \in \bf R$:
looking around $\ker A = {\rm span} \lbrace(-1,c)\rbrace$
we find the negative vector $v = (-c, c^2+1)$.
To verify that $\langle v, Dv \rangle < 0$, recall that
for any vector $x$ and any symmetric matrix $M$ of the same order we have
$$
\langle x, M^2 x \rangle = \langle Mx, Mx \rangle = |Mx|^2.
$$
Here we compute $v(A+B) = (0,1)$ and $v(A-B) = (2c,1)$, so
$$
\langle v, Dv \rangle = c \phantom. |(0,1)|^2 - |(2c,1)|^2 = -4c^2 + c - 1,
$$
which is negative for all real $c$.  If $c$ is small enough that
$\det(D) > 0$ then $D$ is *negative* definite.

Comment: You're welcome!  I thought the minimal $c$ might grow with the dimension $n$, and tried some pairs of rank-1 matrices for $n=2$ (because they form the boundary of the positive-semidefinite cone), and when $A = ({1 \phantom+ 1 \atop 1 \phantom+ 1})$ and $B = ({1 \phantom+ 0 \atop 0 \phantom+ 0})$ produced a surprisingly large $c$ of almost $6$ I tried varying $A$ and soon found that already for $n=2$ the minimal $c$ can get arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 3):

A weaker version is also not true, that is, there is no constant $c$ such that 
$$\lambda_j(A-B)^2 \leq c \lambda_j(A+B)^2, ~~ j=1, 2,\ldots$$
where $\lambda_j(A)$ means the $j$-th largest eigenvalue of $A$.

Nevertheless, it is trivial to see that
$$trace(A-B)^2 \leq  trace(A+B)^2.$$